# Writing a GIF file in Java

Tags: java, gif

So I have this GIF file on my desktop (it's a 52 card deck of poker cards). I have been working on a program that cuts it up into little acm.graphics.GImages of each card. Now, however, I want to write those GImages or pixel arrays to a file so that I can use them later. I thought it would be as straight forward as writing .txt files, but a couple of Google searches later I am more confused than before.

So how do I go about making .gif files out of pixel arrays or GImages (I've got loads of both)?

Comment: What is a GImage? What library is this? (Or what is the package import if you don't know?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick (modify the image type, dimensions and pixel array as appropriate):

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
for ( i=0; i<width; i++ ) {
    for (  j=0; j<height; j++ ) {
        int[] colorArray = getColorForPixel(pixels[i][j]);
        raster.setPixel(i, j, colorArray);
    }
}

ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File("CardImage"));
```

'getColorForPixel' will need to return an array representing the color for this pixel. In this case, using RGB, the colorArray will have three integers [red][green][blue].

Relevant javadoc: [WritableRaster](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html), [BufferedImage](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

Comment: pixels is an int[][] of pixels yes?

Comment: Nope, my first answer was actually incorrect (sorry). Hopefully the edit will help. Unfortunately the javadoc for this method doesn't do a good job of describing what the array needs to be.

Comment: also! Having trouble with BufferedImage.TYPE_RGB trouble of the "cannot be resolved" variety"...

Comment: Oh and what doc are you looking at! I should know that too!

Comment: I added the javadoc links to the answer.

Comment: Oh man, I am not getting this at all. So I have this image, and I converted it into an in[][] parts of which I used in the constructors of 52 GImages. But I don't know how to ask an int for it's color? I mean, come on! GImage knows how, but not I.

Comment: Create an java.awt.Color with the int using this constructor:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)
Then use Color.getRed(), Color.getGreen() and Color.getBlue() to construct the int[] for the pixel color.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create GIF's out of Java Images for a university project, and I found this.
I would recommend Acme's Open-Source GifEncoder Class. Nice and easy to use, I still remember it over 2 years later.
Here's the link: http://www.acme.com/java/software/Acme.JPM.Encoders.GifEncoder.html

And here's the G-Link: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=acme+java+gif&btnG=Search

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't really answer your question directly, but wouldn't it be easier to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)?  It has [Java bindings](http://www.jmagick.org).